# How to Install spark client on AWS EC2?

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-ec2, amazon-emr

How to install spark client on AWS EC2, where spark job will be submitted to EMR master node having clustered worker nodes?

Could you please point me to documentation configure spark in above architecture.

Answer (score 2):

you can check AWS EMR documentation for more details at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-launch.html

The following command that I use to launch AWS EMR cluster using AWS CLI

```
aws emr create-cluster --release-label emr-5.10.0 \
--name 'My Cluster' \
--applications Name=Hadoop Name=Spark \
--service-role EMR_DefaultRole \
--ec2-attributes KeyName=<my_key_file_name> \
--instance-groups Name=MASTER,InstanceGroupType=MASTER,InstanceCount=1,InstanceType=r4.2xlarge Name=CORE,InstanceGroupType=CORE,InstanceCount=4,InstanceType=r4.xlarge Name=TASK,InstanceGroupType=TASK,InstanceCount=25,InstanceType=r4.xlarge,BidPrice=0.10 \
--region us-east-2 \
--log-uri 's3n://cv-e2deep-emr/emr-logs/' \
--use-default-roles \
--enable-debugging
```

You can add your spark job as **`step`** to the cluster. Whenever AWS completes setting up the cluster, it will trigger that spark job.

Check the documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-submit-step.html

Step will look like below:

```
--steps Type=Spark,Name="Spark Program",ActionOnFailure=CONTINUE,Args=[--class,org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi,/usr/lib/spark/lib/spark-examples.jar,10]
```

For complete information check the documentation:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark.html